# Pfsense problem with Cloned VMs in Proxmox

Tags: pfsense

I found this issue while creating a separated VLAN for my Proxmox server. It seems like that cloned VMs pass the same client identifiers, even though they have different MAC addresses.

This issue will make the VM to acquired the same IP addresses and/or not be able to renew it and acquire a new one.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server/VM configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this you need to log into the Pfsense gui and go to DHCP Server and select "Ignore client identifiers". This should solve the issue as Pfsense will not identify the cloned VMs as being the same machine.

Comment: Or go to the VM and change the ID it's using.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the system is not use a MAC (chaddr) as it's client identifier. Systems that do not use hardware / environment elements in their id will have this issue. (i.e. the on-disk client configuration has an id in it that won't change when the hardware changes, and thus when the system is replicated, the client identifier is not (re)generated.)